# magento 2 - dynamic images not showing in home page

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

after installing magento 2, dynamic images (Products/Slider/Blogs) are displaying in all website pages but not in home pages
i cleared the cache, re-indexed the website and changes the media folder permission but none of them solve my problem

Comment: There could be multiple reasons, please check this [link](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.simicart.com/blog/magento-images-not-showing/amp/)

Comment: thanks adeel for ur reply, i already tried them, also plz note that images not shown only in homepage, and displaying well in other frontend pages